# snmpwalk with python scrypt

Tags: python, snmp

I tried to build a python script to get temperature from snmp sensor.

If I use this command line with a Linux terminal

```
snmpwalk 10.100.2.21 -On -v 1 -c public .1.3.6.1.4.1.28507.14.1.3.1.1.2.2
```

Output is correct :

```
.1.3.6.1.4.1.28507.14.1.3.1.1.2.2 = INTEGER: 225
```

In fact  it return temperature :-) 22.5 °C
But I must use a python script :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: latin-1 -*-
import netsnmp
#oid = '.1.3.6.1.4.1.28507.14.1.3.1.1.2.2'
oid =   netsnmp.VarList(netsnmp.Varbind('.1.3.6.1.4.1.28507.14.1.3.1.1.2.2'))
print ("Hello !!!")
res = netsnmp.snmpwalk(oid, Version=1, DestHost='10.100.2.21',   Community='public')
print res
```

I don't know why, my script return only :

```
 "()"
```

Have you some ides ?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

The constructs for netsnmp don't work that way. As far as I know, you need to open a snmp session before making queries.

I usually do:

```
session=netsnmp.Session(DestHost=myip, Version=2, Community='public', RemotePort=161)
```

Then you can check if you got a proper session:

```
if session:
  continue
else:
  print sys.exc_info()
  exit(1)
```

Finally:

```
myoid=netsnmp.VarList('.1.3.6.1.4.1.28507.14.1.3.1.1.2.2')
res=snmp.walk(myoid)
for i in res:
  print i
```

I am using a for loop, because you chose `snmp.walk()`, that could potentially return many rows of values. You could use `snmp.get()` instead